# Flutter error when using audioplayer packages

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-packages

im new in flutter and i followed londonappbrewery course, in that course she teach us to use audioplayer packages so im follow her and import it on pubspec.yaml but when i want to run my flutter app it give this error, i tried to search the problem but i can't figure it out and i also upgrade my flutter to the latest version but the problem still remains. So i hope someone can help me with this problem and sorry for my bad english.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you have to upgrade your minSDK to api level 23 in build.gradle file. But notice that doing this will make your app not working on phones below Android 6.0 so instead you can just downgrade the version of the package.

Comment: Thanks i dowgraded the version package but a new error comes, so i tried to change minSDK to level 23 and now the error was gone.

Comment: Good you can mark my answer as the correct one then.